# How to exclude more than one specific documents in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here, I want to exclude the document of the user who is requesting for the response as well as all those users whom the user has already send friendrequests and the users who are already friend with user, how can I achieve this?

From following code I am able to only exclude user data not other's.

```js
try {
      
      const {id} = req.params
      const user = await userModel.findById(id)
   
      const newresponse = await userModel.find({_id:user.friendRequests}).select("_id")
      
      const response = await userModel.find({_id:{"$ne":id}}).sort({creation_date:-1}).limit(5)
      return res.json({succcess:true, response, newresponse})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error); 
    }
```

model:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  password: String,
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  birthday: Date,
  creation_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  gender: String,
  profile_picture: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  friends:[{
    type:mongoose.ObjectId,
    ref:"userModel"
  }],
  friendRequests:[{
    type:mongoose.ObjectId,
    ref:"userModel"
  }]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("userModel", userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate `friends` and `friendRequests` arrays and pass that to the filter:

```js
const { id } = req.params;

const user = await userModel.findById(id, 'friends friendRequests');

const excludeUsersArray = user.friends.concatenate(user.friendRequests);
   
const response = await userModel.find({ _id: { "$nin": excludeUsersArray }}).sort({ creation_date:-1 });
      
return res.json({succcess:true, response})
```

Comment: It returns a error saying `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[new ObjectId("Sth")]" (type Array) at path "_id" for model "userModel`

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. Instead of `$ne`, it should be `$nin` operator.